Is the implementation of the medical specialty property in json-ld schema markup correct?
Is the use of medicalSpeciality property in Physician type schema correct? If it is not correct can someone tell me what is the correct method?
Also, what to do if the medical speciality is not present on schema.org as specified here,
https://schema.org/MedicalSpecialty
I searched the entire internet and could not find anything.
Please help
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Physician",
    "name": "Dr Name",
    "url": "",
    "priceRange": "₹500-₹2,000",
    "alternateName": "Dr.Name",
    "image": "https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in/images/doctors/Dr-Abhilasha-Pandey.jpg",
    "description": "Dr. Namde' is the best doctor for piles treatment,hernia treatment,varicose veins treatment,fistula treatment,pilonidal sinus treatment and constipation treatment in India",
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "worstRating": "1",
        "reviewCount": "1541"
    },
    "hospitalAffiliation": {
        "@type": "Hospital",
        "name": "...",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "addressLocality": "Pune",
            "postalCode": "412105",
            "addressRegion": "MH",
            "addressCountry": "IN"
        },
        "geo": {
            "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
            "latitude": "Coordinate 1",
            "longitude": "Coordinate 2"
        }
    },
    "sameAs": [
        "https://www....",
        "https://www....",
        "https://www...."
    ],
    "availableService": [
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "TRENDELENBERG SURGERY / OPEN SURGERY"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
            "name": "LIFESTYLE MODIFICATIONS"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
            "name": "MEDICATION"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
            "name": "MCDPA"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
            "name": "BIOFEEDBACK"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalTherapy",
            "name": "VENOUS STOCKINGS / COMPRESSION STOCKINGS"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "LIGATION AND STRIPPING"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "INGUINAL HERNIA REPAIR SURGERY"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "FEMORAL HERNIA REPAIR SURGERY"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "UMBILICAL HERNIA REPAIR SURGERY"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "EPIGASTRIC AND INCISIONAL HERNIA REPAIR"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "Endovenous Laser Ablation (EVLA)"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "STARR SURGERY"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "WIDE EXCISION OF PILONIDAL SINUS"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "Fistulectomy"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "FiLaC ( Fistula-tract Laser Closure )"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "FISTULA PLUG"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "Wide excision "
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "LASER PILONIDOPLASTY ( LPP )"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "Z-PLASTY"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "CLEFT LIFT / MODIFIED KARYADAKIS / CLEFT CLOSURE"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "LIMBERG FLAP / GLUTEAL FLAP"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "MIPH ( Minimally Invasive Procedure for Haemorrhoids ) aka PPH ( Procedure for Prolapse and Haemorrhoids ) aka Stapler Haemorrhoidopexy"
        },
        {
            "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
            "name": "LASER HAEMORRHOIDOPLASTY ( LHP ) aka Laser treatment for Piles"
        }
    ],
    "telephone": "..",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "..",
        "addressLocality": "..",
        "postalCode": "..",
        "addressRegion": "..",
        "addressCountry": ".."
    },
    "geo": {
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude": "...",
        "longitude": "..."
    },
    "medicalSpecialty": [
        {
            "@type": "DefinedTerm",
            "name": "Varicose Veins Treatment",
            "url": "https://..."
        },
        {
            "@type": "DefinedTerm",
            "name": "Hernia Treatment",
            "url": "https://..."
        },
        {
            "@type": "DefinedTerm",
            "name": "Constipation Treatment",
            "url": "https://..."
        },
        {
            "@type": "DefinedTerm",
            "name": "Fistula Treatment",
            "url": "https://..."
        },
        {
            "@type": "DefinedTerm",
            "name": "Pilonidal Sinus Treatment",
            "url": "https://..."
        },
        {
            "@type": "DefinedTerm",
            "name": "Piles Treatment",
            "url": "https://..."
        }
    ],
    "hasCredential": {
        "@type": "EducationalOccupationalCredential",
        "name": "BHMS",
        "credentialCategory": "degree"
    }
}
</script>


Test your code with: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results
(looks fine)
